# Mysql Error 1064, Синтактическая ошибка

Tags: mysql, bash

**UPD**
Помогите найти синтактическую ошибку в коде:

```
#!/bin/sh

db_user="test"
db_pass="test"
db_host="192.168.10.56"
db_name="test"
exec_db="mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p$db_pass -D $db_name -N -s -e"
ip_list="/tmp/ip.list"

    echo "Start scanning network (`date`) ..."
    $exec_db "SELECT DISTINCT ip_address FROM devices" > $ip_list
    active_ip=`nmap -sP -iL $ip_list | grep -P -o "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+" | sed "s/^.*$/'\0'/g" | tr '\n' ',' | sed "s/,$//g"`

    if [ -z active_ip ]; then
        echo "nmap scanning failed"
        exit 1
    fi

    $exec_db "UPDATE devices SET status=1 WHERE ip_address IN ($active_ip)"
    $exec_db "UPDATE devices SET status=0 WHERE ip_address NOT IN ($active_ip)"
    echo "Done (`date`)"
```

Я предполагаю что ошибка в `WHERE`, но без него скрипт не будет работать, как его написать/расположить так, чтобы Mysql не давал ошибку?
Сама ошибка:

```
Start scanning network (Mon Jan 25 10:30:29 UZT 2016) ...
Invalid target host specification: ---
QUITTING!
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
Done (Mon Jan 25 10:30:29 UZT 2016)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35213/discussion-on-question-by-tristar-mysql-error-1064--).